# Retrieve username by userid without instagram api

Tags: c#, json, instagram-api

I'm searching for posts with a tag by using the following url, which returns a Json with all the lastest posts, but it returns only userid, not the username.

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/neymar/?__a=1

I'd like to know if there is a way to retrieve the username for a Instagram profile without using the official API and passing by the userid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found out that If I use the post code in the following URL it will return a JSON with the owner:username.

https://www.instagram.com/p/BVs_bQtjmov/?__a=1

```
"owner":{
"id":"-------",
"profile_pic_url":"-",
"username":"neymarjr",
```